# Deleting youtube google plus threaded comments through the api

Tags: youtube-api, google-plus

Is it possible to delete google plus threaded replies to youtube comments through either the youtube API or the google plus API?

Comment: It is not possible through the G+ API and I don't think YouTube has a comments accessible through their API.

Comment: Check it out https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup . It might help

Comment: Thank you abraham and vh5 for your suggestions. It looks like I can delete threaded comments on behalf of a page but not for a user. Is there a way I can give you both credit for your answers?